# Is there a way to configure the version of the Maven POM from command line?

Tags: java, maven, continuous-integration, maven-3

Is there a way to change the version number without editing the POM?

```
<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<artifactId>example</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
```

We have a CI system where we want to release nightly builds, but without using the `-SNAPSHOT`  solution of Maven, so if `1.0.0` is the current version, we just want to have `CI-NIGHTLY-BIULD-20120426`.

I suggested this would be possible with something like `mvn deploy -Dversion=CI-NIGHTLY-BIULD-20120426`, but obviously not. The bad solution would be to let the CI server edit the `pom.xml` every time, but I think this is very unhandy.

Thank you!

Comment: If your problem is with -SNAPSHOT not being unique, I believe latest version of Nexus automatically timestamps the release and installs even the snapshots with unique names.

Comment: Why not using SNAPSHOT thats exactly for such purposes. Otherwise why not using releases ? (mvn release:...via CI)..?

Comment: Ok, maybe I hid to much informations, we also have a staged CI so we release not only nightly also when several requirements are fulfilled, so we need to change the version from `1.0.0` to `1.0.0-STABLE` or `1.0.0-NIGHTLY` to separate them.

Comment: Publishing a version like "1.0-SNAPSHOT" to a Nexus snapshot repository will automtically generate a revision with a timestamp. More importantly other projects an either refer to the "1.0-SNAPSHOT" and automatically receive the latest revision, or specify the timestamped edition. This would be the simplest solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest to use classifier.

```
<groupId>foo</groupId>
<artifactId>bar</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>

<properties>
    <!-- default classifier is empty -->
    <my.project.classifier></my.project.classifier>
</properties>

<build>
...
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <classifier>${my.project.classifier}</classifier>
    </configuration>
    <executions>...</executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

and

```
mvn package -Dmy.project.classifier=NIGHTLY-2012-04-26_02-30
```

---

Maven [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html) says about classifier:

> classifier: You may occasionally find a fifth element on the
>   coordinate, and that is the classifier. We will visit the classifier
>   later, but for now it suffices to know that those kinds of projects
>   are displayed as groupId:artifactId:packaging:classifier:version.

and

> The classifier allows to distinguish artifacts that were built from
>   the same POM but differ in their content. It is some optional and
>   arbitrary string that - if present - is appended to the artifact name
>   just after the version number. As a motivation for this element,
>   consider for example a project that offers an artifact targeting JRE
>   1.5 but at the same time also an artifact that still supports JRE 1.4. The first artifact could be equipped with the classifier jdk15 and the
>   second one with jdk14 such that clients can choose which one to use.
>
> Another common use case for classifiers is the need to attach
>   secondary artifacts to the project's main artifact. If you browse the
>   Maven central repository, you will notice that the classifiers sources
>   and javadoc are used to deploy the project source code and API docs
>   along with the packaged class files.

Comment: Thats a nice idea. Although I am not sure if you can keep the classifier blank in case of normal builds?

Answer (score 2):

I think you could also use [versions](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/) maven plugin. I find it quite useful for things like this.

You could do it in 2 steps:

1. set necessary version: `mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=CI-NIGHTLY-BIULD-20120426`
2. deploy: `mvn deploy`
3. in case you need to revert back the changes, use `mvn versions:revert` (as Mark suggests)

Comment: You can add a step 3 which will return the POM back to it's original state: "mvn versions:revert"

Comment: @MarkO'Connor You're right, I've edited my answer to include this detail.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend reading [Maven Releases on Steroids](http://www.axelfontaine.com/2011/01/maven-releases-on-steroids-adios.html) ([part 2](http://www.axelfontaine.com/2011/01/maven-releases-on-steroids-2-preparing.html), [part 3](http://www.axelfontaine.com/2011/02/maven-releases-on-steroids-3-rounding.html)) by Axel Fontaine. It is great, and I'm quite happy using it.

It not only details how you con do what you ask, but also contains good advice how you can tie your build versions with your CI server.

In a nutshell, here are the main points:

1. Maven Release is slow, needs to be done faster
2. You parametarize your project version like

   ```
   <version>${VERSION_NUMBER}</version>
   ...
   <properties>
   ...
       <VERSION_NUMBER>1.0-SNAPSHOT</VERSION_NUMBER>
   ...
   </properties>
   ```
3. Local builds get that version: `1.0-SNAPSHOT`
4. Release builds are done **only** from your CI server
5. In your Jenkins/Hudson project configuration you use

   ```
   clean deploy scm:tag -DVERSION_NUMBER=${BUILD_NUMBER}
   ```

That way you get a new release with each Jenkins build, not only nightly.

You can change the configuration to use

```
clean deploy scm:tag -DVERSION_NUMBER=1.0.0-CI-NIGHTLY-BIULD-${BUILD_ID}
```

and you would get versions like `1.0.0-CI-NIGHTLY-BIULD-2012-04-26_12-20-24`

Answer (score 0):

You could parameterize the version number as

```
<groupId>foo</groupId>
<artifactId>bar</artifactId>
<version>${my.project.version}</version>

<properties>
    <my.project.version>1.0</my.project.version>
</properties>
```

and drive the version number from command line using

```
mvn package -Dmy.project.version=NIGHTLY
```

Although this is possible, Maven 3 discourages it.

Comment: Thank you, but it seems that this will be deprecated in the near future.

Comment: Indeed. That is why i put the disclaimer.

Comment: This will not work, you cannot pass property identifier to version, Maven will complain.